# unnecessary usage of would

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, will-would

I have seen this sentence in an online learning website:

> Let's delve into the problem you'd like to solve

I can't get why would is used in this sentence?

what this the difference between this sentence and this one:

> Let's delve into the problem you like to solve.

Comment: The difference between something you ***do*** and something you ***would*** do is simply that the latter is "hypothetical". You might never have actually done that specific thing before, but *in the relevant circumstances*, nobody would be surprised to see you doing it (again, or for the first time; in many contexts ***would*** implies nothing about that). In your example, it seems unlikely the addressee is known for liking to solve *that exact* problem, so you should probably include ***would***.

Comment: Note that *I'd like to solve this problem* doesn't normally imply *solving this problem is something I would **enjoy doing***. Normally when people say that, what they mean is they would like the problem ***to be solved*** (perhaps even by someone else). What they hope to enjoy is the fact of the problem being solved (in some hypothetical future), not the actual solving itself.

Answer (score 1):

By saying "problem you would like to solve" you are saying this is a problem you view as necessary to solve, I disagree about whether it means you enjoy it or not, it just means you view it as necessary.

By saying "problem you like to solve" you definitely are saying this is a problem you enjoy solving.